# PyFlink: What's the best way to provide reference data and keep them uptated

Tags: python, apache-flink, pyflink

I have a use case where I want to do comparisons between incoming data and some reference data provided by another service.

What's the best way in `pyflink` to fetch those data and update them regularly (in intervals of 1-2 hours)

Other considerations:

- The reference data may contain hundreds of thousands of records